# currency converter from USD to EUR or any other currency in html and java script

Tags: javascript, html, concurrency, converters

i want to convert currencies but this one didn't work for me
    
     
        Convert US Dollars to Euros 2

Amount:

From 
              
                USD
                EUR
                
            To 
            
              USD
              EUR

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function calculate() {
        var amount = parseFloat(document.getElementById("amount").value);
        var select = document.getElementById("select");
        var select = document.getElementById("select2");

        var result = document.getElementById("result");

        if ((select.value == "USD" ) && (select.value == "EUR")){

            result.value = (amount * 0.7003).toFixed(2);
        }


        else if ((select.value === "EUR") && (select.value == "USD")) {
            result.value = (amount * 1.4283).toFixed(2);
        }
        else  {
             result.value = (amount);
        }

    }
</script>
</body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't give one name to the variable pointing to the two different DOM elements and expect them to behave the way you want. You should use different names (for example, *select1* and *select2*), like it is shown in the example below:

```
   function calculate() {
    var amount = parseFloat(document.getElementById("amount").value)
    var select1 = document.getElementById("select")
    var select2 = document.getElementById("select2")
    var result = document.getElementById("result")

    if ((select1.value == "USD" ) && (select2.value == "EUR")){
        result.value = (amount * 0.7003).toFixed(2)
    } else if ((select1.value == "EUR") && (select2.value == "USD")) {
        result.value = (amount * 1.4283).toFixed(2)
    } else {
        result.value = (amount)
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Extending the **Notulysses**' answer,
`selectFrom` and `selectTo` would be more talkative.

Comment: Probably something more along the lines of `soureCurrency` and `destinationCurrency`, but yes, you're right about using more descriptive names.